# There is a round cake. What is the chance of cutting a piece of cake with angle of $30°$/$30°$ or less?

Tags: probability

Problem statement:

> There is a round cake. What is the chance of cutting a piece of cake (cutting two radiuses) with the angle of:
>
> 1. $30°$ or less?
> 2. $30°$?

In our class, our teacher and other students suggested two solutions and two different answers for  question number 1:

#### First Solution

> As there are unlimited number of possible cutting angles, We indicate the probability with area. $30°$ is $\frac1{12}$ of the area of the cake, so probability is $\frac1{12}$.

#### Second Solution

> Suppose that we have made the first cut. Then the angle of the wanted are is $60°$ because wanted cases can happen if you cut from $30°$ or less degrees from right or left. Take a look at this picture:
>
> [image]
>
> So the wanted area is $\frac1{6}$ of the whole cake, so probability is $\frac16$.

If you think one of these solutions is true, please explain why other one is wrong.

And about the question number 2, I've no idea about how to answer.

Answer (score 1):

The first solution is incorrect. When calculating probabilities by finding area, you're finding the probability that one random outcome lands in a particular region. For example, the probability that a spinner lands in a certain segment of a board is the angle of that segment divided by $360$ degrees. So the area of a $30$ degree slice is the probability that a *single* random cut will be somewhere on that slice.

The second argument is correct, because it doesn't matter where the first cut is. You just need the second cut to be within the $60$ degree slice centered on the first cut.

As for the second question, you could think about it in a similar way: assume the first cut has been made. What is the probability that the second slice lands *exactly* $30$ degrees clockwise or counterclockwise from the first? Now you want the second slice to land on one of two particular lines. If we keep thinking about probability as area, we need the area of those lines. But the area of a line is...

Comment: I don't see the explanation for incorrectness of the first solution enough. what about this: "Just cut a 30 degree piece, put its angle on the center and spin it." As you can see, there is an unlimited number of possible cuts ... maybe there is something wrong with what i think ... but i think this can't be a proof of its incorrectness.

Comment: The problem is "cut a 30 degree piece, put its angle on the center and spin it" doesn't correspond to what the problem asks. You have not argued why that should give you the probability you want. If you provide an argument for why that should be the desired probability, I can show you where that argument fails, but right now there is no argument.